# Image detection in real time

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipod-touch, ipa

In my prototype I have to detect an image in real time,  when an camera view is opened through my application it starts to capture through its view port now I am able to access the video frames individually using AVFoundation framework but I want to compare each and every frames with the images saved in the data base and show an alert if any match found.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Not sure what your question is? "How do I extract a still image from a video stream?", "How do I compare an image to one in a database?" What have you tried so far? What is the format of your video stream?

Comment: I want to identify mac mine from my application when I open a camera view from my application and hold it in front of macmine I have to display an alert view telling that it is a mac mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really suggest to use **OpenCV** it's a library with support for iOS as long as I know.

I've been using it with Python and C++ and prooved is a really powerful library.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Comment: You should also try out SimpleCV which is easier to install, configure and even code...I think objects and features recognition would be better with it